# reloadRootControllersWithNames:contexts: does not load new InterfaceControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I have my WatchKit app (WatchOS1) set up in the following way (names have been changed to be project unspecific):

`InitialInterfaceController` - The `main` entry point of the watch app. This controller is only used to load several instances (using the same identifier repeatedly in the `NSArray`) of the next view using `reloadRootControllersWithNames:contexts:` (called from `awakeWithContext:`).

`FirstInterfaceController` - This Interface controller should be what is first displayed for the pages.

However this does not work - I get left with the blank `InitialInterfaceController` screen. If however I call `[self presentControllerWithNames:contexts:]` it works as expected, but includes the cancel button, which is not what I want.

I have seen people suggesting to use this method to dynamically create multiple page navigation scenes, but I cannot see why this doesn't work. The `FirstInterfaceController`'s `awakeWithContext:` is never called.

Has anybody had this problem or is there a fix available?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. I suppose this is a bug with the WatchKit SDK 1, especially on phones running iOS 9 beta. It looks to work appropriately on watch OS 2.

Comment: @romrom thank you this is good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the right value for the `Identity` in the interface controller's attribute inspector? (I have seen issues when the identity and class name are the same, make sure they are different)

Is that interface controller added to the right `module` in the identity inspector?